# Creating array of methods returning boolean and iterating through for-each loop

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Okay so I have a batch of methods returning `boolean` values of `true/false`.

```
private void saveChangesOnEditButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
        updateMainTabsAccess();
        updateUserPaymentTabPermissions();
        updateUserRegistrationTabPermissions();
        updateUserStudentsTabPermissions();
        updateUserFacultyTabPermissions();
        updateUserHomePermissions(); //saves any update made on existing user settings/permissions
        updateUserInformation(); // sasve any update made on existing user information such as username
    }
```

I would like to know if it's possible for me to check each of the methods' return value through a for-each loop.

I'm thinking of creating a `private boolean isUpdateSuccessful()` method.
Say like,

```
private boolean isUpdateSuccessful(){
    Boolean a = updateMainTabsAccess();
    Boolean b = updateUserPaymentTabPermissions();
    //........so on....
    Boolean result = (a && b &&...)
    return result;
}
```

Problem is, I don't know if it's possible to put them in an arraylist or component array like

```
ArrayList<Boolean> listOfMethods = new ArrayList<Boolean>(method1,method2..);
```

So that I can then check each through a `for-each` loop

```
for(Boolean b:listOfMethods){
    Boolean successful=true;
    successful =  (successful && b)
}
```

My questions are:

1.) How do I extract the return values of these methods and use the methods to initialize the `Arraylist`.

2.) Using `for-each` loop, is there any possibility of what I'm trying to do? I none, then what do you suggest I do?

I'd appreciate any answer or suggestion. I simply want to check if every method was successful. I thought of using `?1:0:`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I am you, I would do this. Just a sample code:

```
private void saveChangesOnEditButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (updateMainTabsAccess()) {
        if (updateUserPaymentTabPermissions()) {
            if (updateUserRegistrationTabPermissions()) {
                ...
            } else {
                // error on update registration
            }
        } else {
            // error on update payment
        }
    }
```

With the above style:

- You don't execute other methods when the before one fails.
- Can have detailed error messages for each error.
- You need not to main a collection and iteration.

Comment: This can lead to many `if`s under other `if`s. Three levels is a maximum. After the code starts to being difficult to read or worse unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `Stream` to check the results:

```
Stream.<Boolean>of(updateMainTabsAccess(),
    updateUserPaymentTabPermissions(),
    updateUserRegistrationTabPermissions(),
    updateUserStudentsTabPermissions(),
    updateUserFacultyTabPermissions(),
    updateUserHomePermissions(),
    updateUserInformation()).allMatch(b -> b);
```

this way you get rid of short circuit evaluation and also don't need to create method references for each method.

#### method references

```
List<Supplier<Boolean>> methods = Arrays.asList(this::updateMainTabsAccess,
                                                this::updateUserPaymentTabPermissions,
                                                ...
);

for (Supplier<Boolean> supplier : methods) {
    boolean methodResult = supplier.get();
    ...
}
```

This can hardly be considered an improvement though...

Answer (score 1):

this will find all method in side your class which is return Boolean after automatically invoke method one by one and store response to successful variable

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Class c = test.getClass();      
        boolean successful = true; 
        for (Method method : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (method.getReturnType().toString().equals("boolean")) {
                    try {
                        String mname = method.getName();
                        Object o = method.invoke(test, null);
                        System.out.format("%s() returned %b%n", mname, (Boolean) o);
                        successful =  successful && (Boolean) o;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }       
        System.out.println("final answer : " + successful);
    }

    public boolean a() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean b() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean c() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope its help to you.

Comment: This is an evolutive solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every method to be executed and check if every method scucceded you could simply write

```
boolean success = updateMainTabsAccess() &
    updateUserPaymentTabPermissions() &
    updateUserRegistrationTabPermissions() &
    updateUserStudentsTabPermissions() &
    updateUserFacultyTabPermissions() &
    updateUserHomePermissions() &
    updateUserInformation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already received some answers.
Fabian's is a good one if you are using java 8.

But to answer directly your points

> 1.) How do I extract the return values of these methods and use the methods to initialize the Arraylist.

```
    ArrayList<Boolean> resultsList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    resultsList.add(updateMainTabsAccess());
    ...
```

> 2.) Using for-each loop, is there any possibility of what I'm trying to do? I none, then what do you suggest I do?

```
    boolean res = true;

    for (Boolean singleResult : resultsList) {
        res = res && singleResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the old style way to acheive your goal when Lambdas weren't introduced by Java 8.

```
public class TestMethodsListCall {

    public abstract class Checker {
        public abstract boolean check();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestMethodsListCall();
    }

    public TestMethodsListCall() {
        final TestMethodsListCall that = this;
        List<Checker> checkers = Arrays.asList( //
                new Checker() { public boolean check() { return that.methodA(); } }, //
                new Checker() { public boolean check() { return that.methodB(); } }  //
                // , ...
        );

        boolean res = true;
        for (Checker c : checkers) {
            res = res & c.check();
            if (!res) {
                // Break, display some message or all together
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean methodA() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean methodB() {
        return false;
    }
}
```